# Google Drive Picker - Allow Folder Creation

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I have currently implemented [Google Drive Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/) on a project and I want to allow the user to create new folders(e.g when uploading files).

So, my question is: does the current version of [Google Drive Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/) have a feature similar to that or is there any way to extend the [Google Drive Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/) and offer this functionality?

I searched on the class reference but didn't find anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive Picker does not allow to create new items. You should implement the Drive REST API which will allow you to create files. You can find more information here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-create#create_a_new_file_from_the_drive_ui